# Intellij Idea community edition commercial?

Tags: 13.04, software-center

I want to install intellij idea. the free edition which is also the community edition. but when i open the software manager and search for it the install button says "buy"? Why do i have to pay for community edition? I am using Ubuntu 13.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, that I've answered before; but I can't find it…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The button says `Buy` because it is an application being distributed via the store side of `software-center`, even though it is free. Simply because the button does say `Buy` doesn't mean you have to pay for it. If the price is `$0.00` as it is in this case, you will not have to pay, or enter any payment details, to purchase the software. You can simply click the button, and it will go through the process to install it.

Comment: It is even libre (open source) software: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community

Comment: Whether something is open source or not is irrelevant. If it is a for purchase application in the software center, it will show a Buy button. Install is only shown for already "purchased" apps, and software in the Ubuntu archives or PPAs.

Answer (score 1):

This is the latest IntelliJ Idea IDE.

```
http://download-ln.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-12.1.3.tar.gz
```

To get it, execute the following commands

```
wget http://download-ln.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-12.1.3.tar.gz
tar -xvf ideaIC-12.1.3.tar.gz
```

Rest of the installation instructions are documented in `Install-Linux-tar.txt` file.